# I don't want to change the values even when user refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, web, timer

I have written a code in javascript for a timer which submits the form when time is up. The problem is if the user refreshes the page the timer is reset how can i avoid this from happening?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var total_seconds = 6*1;
    var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);

    function CheckTime()
{
    document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML
    = 'Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds ' ;

    if(total_seconds <=0)
{
        document.forms['quiz'].submit();
    } 
else
 {
    total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
    c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
    setTimeout("CheckTime()",1000);
    }
}
    setTimeout("CheckTime()",0);
    </script>
```

Comment: `localStorage` perhaps?

Comment: can you explain your purpose why do you want to  preserve value on page refresh

Comment: @Dipakchavda it's a quiz and the user has a limit time until the time is up.

Comment: @Ele not fimiliar with it. Could you guide with a short code.

Comment: as per your description, you wanted to show current timer after refresh page right.

Comment: Check the answer.  It's untested, but that the way using `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using the [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) could be an alternative:**

- **Important:** don't use the function `setTimeout`, use setInterval instead to avoid manually repeated calls of the function `CheckTime`, further, always use camelcase for function's name.
- Check for **[`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)** attribute.

---

```
var total_seconds = 6 * 1;
var currentMinutes = window.localStorage.getItem('currentMinutes');
var currentSeconds = window.localStorage.getItem('currentSeconds');

var c_minutes = currentMinutes ? parseInt(currentMinutes) : parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
var c_seconds = currentSeconds ? parseInt(currentSeconds) : parseInt(total_seconds % 60);

var intervalId;
function checkTime() {
  document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").textContent = 'Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds ';

  if (total_seconds <= 0) {
    //document.forms['quiz'].submit();
    console.log("Time is up!");
    console.log("Submitting...");
    clearInterval(intervalId);

    // Clean the current values
    window.localStorage.removeItem('currentMinutes');
    window.localStorage.removeItem('currentSeconds');
  } else {
    total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
    c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);

    // Store the new calculated minutes and seconds
    window.localStorage.setItem('currentMinutes', c_minutes);
    window.localStorage.setItem('currentSeconds', c_seconds);
  }
}

intervalId = setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
```

- **[`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**

  > The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions. localStorage is similar to **[`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)**, except that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.
- **[`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)**

  > The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. `sessionStorage` is similar to **[window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**; the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated**, which differs from how session cookies work.

Comment: It does show the time before refreshing for a brief second, but then the clock is getting reset again. Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: @MustafaRangwala you're welcome `:)`.  Now you need to make a little debug to understand what's happening!